# How to combine KNN search and msearch in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I perform KNN search on multiple queries efficiently using Elasticsearch's `msearch` API? I have a large number of queries that I need to run and I'd like to avoid looping over each query individually.

Each query is a vector, so KNN search is a must. However, I can't find any examples or documentation on how to combine `msearch` with KNN search in Elasticsearch. Can someone provide an example or point me to relevant documentation on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

I got the example [Aproximation KNN](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/knn-search.html#approximate-knn). I put two queries in multisearch.

```
GET image-index/_msearch
{ }
{"knn":{"field":"image-vector","query_vector":[-5,9,-12],"k":10,"num_candidates":100},"fields":["title","file-type"]}
{"index": "new index "}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}}
```

Comment: may I know which version of Elasticsearch you are using?

Comment: I using Elasticsearch v8.5

Comment: Let's say I have 2 queries, each is a vector [-5,9,-12] and [6,7,-3]. How should I write the query?

Comment: like this:
GET image-index/_msearch
{ }
{"knn":{"field":"image-vector","query_vector":[-5,9,-12],"k":10,"num_candidates":100},"fields":["title","file-type"]}
{"index": "image-index"}
{"knn":{"field":"image-vector","query_vector":[6,7,-3],"k":10,"num_candidates":100},"fields":["title","file-type"]}}